# Why does attachInterrupt() not run even though my interrupt pin is changing from LOW to HIGH / HIGH to LOW?

Tags: arduino, interrupts, arduino-uno

I have an arduino uno and I am running this code here:

```
int fase;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(8, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(8), func, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
int e = digitalRead(8);
Serial.println(e);
  if (fase == 1) {
    Serial.println("fase 1 baby");
  }
  delay(500);
}

void func() {
  fase = 1;
}
```

As you can see I am attaching a simple interrupt statement that should print out the statement "fase 1 baby" when pin 8 changes states.

Here is a screenshot of what I see on the Serial Monitor:

[image: Serial Monitor]

I am simply switching pin 8 HIGH and then back to LOW and vice versa, but for some reason the serial monitor still won't print the "fase 1 baby" which means the function `func()` isn't running. Why is this not running even though the interrupt is changing states?

Comment: Happens due to compiler optimization on the ISR-main common variable `fase` .. Change it to `volatile` type....

Answer (score 4):

You should probably declare `fase` as `volatile` since it's modified in an interrupt handler and then you should also be mindful to access it atomically when you read it.

Comment: I added `volatile` in front of fase now so thanks for that :), but what exactly do you mean by "access it atomically when you read it"?

Comment: @alanfats For single byte variables, you might be able to make due without it, but for reference, avr-gcc has some helpers for this sort of thing: https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__atomic.html. If you read volatile variables without such guards, you are liable to get some intermediate state of a partially written multi-byte value. That can lead to "interesting" behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem explained in all tutorials how to use variables between interrupts and normal code in AVR-GCC, including the interrupts section of AVR-GCC manual and likely Arduino too. If a tutorial does not mention this, you can stop reading it.

The C compiler is told to optimize the genrated code so it is smaller in size and runs faster because it can assume things about the code.

In your case, the compiler has optimized the use of your flag variable. It likely uses registers for storing the value so it never reads the memory address of that variable.

The compiler cannot determine that the flag variable can change because it can only see a function being called that reads the variable, as it can't see any code that would call the function that changes the flag variable.

So by adding the volatile keyword to a variable, you as the programmer are telling the compiler to forcibly read the variable value always when it is needed, as the value may change under the hood for some reason.